# Finding an angle in a pyramid

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

We have a straight pyramid with a square ABCD as its base and apex S. We're given the pyramid's height 8 and the angle 48 deg. between SA and SC. I've already managed to calculate the pyramid's volume (67.66 cubic meters). and now I'm asked to find the angle between the height SO (O=center of the square base = intersection point of its diagonals) and the pyramid's face SBC. I tried the triangle SOE , E=midpoint of BC, but I can't explain why this works: I know I must draw a perpendicular to plane SBC from some point on SO, yet OE definitely isn't this perpendicular. All I need is to show such perpendicular MUST intersect the line SE at some point
is it possible to express the pyramid´s volume with the wanted angle?
[image: This is how the pyramid looks like]

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect your last question has a positive answer, @AdirPmon, yet I can't see any direct relation off the top of my head...interesting question, indeed!

Comment: I cannot really understand this problem. If the $\widehat{ASC}$ angle and the height $h=d(S,ABCD)$ are known, $S$ can lie anywhere on a circle that lies on a plane parallel to base, so how can we compute the angle between two given faces?